# Angular/RxJS Should I unsubscribe on every ajax call?

Tags: ajax, angular, rxjs

Should I unsubscribe on every ajax call? According to the RxJS contract, I should. Because AJAX calls are not streams or events, once they are done they are done. What is the reason of using RxJS at all in this particular case? Overtime it becomes the mess (I know about takeUntil, that's not the point here).

```
public remove(data: IData): void {
  // unsubscribe from the previous possible call
  if (this.dataSubscription &&
      this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe) {
    this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
  this.dataSubscription = this.dataService
    .delete(data.id)
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.refresh();
    });
}

public ngOnDestroy(): void {
  // unsubscribe on deletion
  if (this.dataSubscription &&
      this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe) {
    this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

What is the advantage over simple promise, that looks cleaner and destroyed right after execution?

```
public remove(data: IData): void {
  this.dataService
    .delete(data.id)
    .then(() => {
      this.refresh();
    });
}
```

This is DataService code

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public delete(id: number): Observable<IModel> {
    return this._httpClient.delete<IModel>(`${this._entityApiUrl}/${id}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: show code for dataService

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com updated the question

Comment: You are asking whether you need to unsubscribe but when people tell you that the unsubscription happens implicitly, you don't accept that answer. What's your *real* question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finite, cold Observables usually don't need to be unsubscribed. They work just like Promises in this regard. Assuming you're using Angular's `HttpClient` in your service, no unsubscription is necessary--it's much like a Promise in that situation.

First off, to clear some things up -- in your Promise example, you are imperatively managing the Promise by assigning it to `this.dataSubscription`. After that call is made, anything that calls `this.dataSubscription.then()` an arbitrary amount of time after the HTTP call will receive a `Promise.resolve()` and invoke that `.then()` function. The new Promise returned by `Promise.resolve()` will be cleaned up after it executes, but it's only until your class is destroyed that your `this.dataSubscription` Promise will be cleaned up.

However, not assigning that Promise as a property is even cleaner:

```
public remove(data: IData): void {
  this.dataService
    .delete(data.id)
    .then(() => {
      this.refresh();
    });
}
```

plus, the Promise will be cleaned up at the end of its scope, not on the destruction of the class.

Observables, at least finite 'Promise-like' ones like this, work in much the same way. You don't need to manage the `Subscription` returned buy the `.subscribe()` method imperitavely, as it will execute and then be cleaned up as it's not assigned as a property:

```
public remove(data: IData): void {
  this.dataService
    .delete(data.id)
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.refresh();
    });
}
```

It's a finite Observable and *completes* after the subscription, so calling `subscribe` again will return a new Subscription and re-call the Observable's function.

Imperitavely managing those subscriptions is indeed messy and usually a sign things could be done better.

The difference with RXJS's subscription management is that RXJS can become an incredibly powerful tool, one that is useful for way, *way* more than managing async AJAX calls. You can have hot Observables that publish data to hundreds of subscribers, Subjects that manage their own stream to many subscribers, infinite Observables that never stop emitting, higher-order Observables that manage state and return other Observables, etc. In this case unsubscribing is *best practice*, but honestly not going to cause performance issues outside of extreme cases.

A good comparison is the `Observable.fromEvent()` property. Just like it's best practice to use `removeEventListener` correctly after `addEventListener`, you should unsubscribe from this Observable correctly. However, just like `removeEventListener`,...it's not really done all the time and usually doesn't cause issues with today's platforms.

Also, in reference to the 'RxJS contract' that was stated: here's an excerpt from the same doc:

`When an Observable issues an OnError or OnComplete notification to its observers, this ends the subscription. Observers do not need to issue an Unsubscribe notification to end subscriptions that are ended by the Observable in this way.`

Finite Observables complete themselves after their emissions and don't need to be unsubscribed.

Comment: "However, not assigning that Promise as a property is even cleaner"


I accidentally left it in the code by doing an example, I would not assign the promise unless I really need to. I will remove it from my question, as the mistake.

Comment: "You don't need to manage the Subscription returned buy the .subscribe() method imperitavely, as it will execute and then be cleaned up as it's not assigned as a property"
That is why I have the issue with this implementation. RxJS states that by the contract, subscription must be unsubscribed. Why default implementation of HttpClient has observable by default, when clearly you should use it when you needed. Speaking of RxJS in general, I admire the idea and it is the powerful tool, but I question this usage

Comment: Observables allow you to easily implement caching of responses using operators like `shareReplay` and are also able to emit these values synchronously. There's plenty of reason to use rxjs over promises even for streams that will only emit once.

Comment: I'm guessing that the RxJS contract you're referring is the Observable contract from the Design Guidelines. That's more of an attempt to define an Observable than of how to implement it, written for translating Rx to other languages. Besides, from the same doc: `When an Observable issues an OnError or OnComplete notification to its observers, this ends the subscription. Observers do not need to issue an Unsubscribe notification to end subscriptions that are ended by the Observable in this way.` Linear, finite Observables complete themselves and don't need to be notified of an unsubscription.

Answer (score 6):

Usually you don't need to unsubscribe from `HttpClient` calls since all `HttpClient` calls complete the stream once they receive response from the server. Once an observable stream completes or errors, its the responsibility of the producer to release resources. For more information, read [Insider’s guide into interceptors and HttpClient mechanics in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/insiders-guide-into-interceptors-and-httpclient-mechanics-in-angular-103fbdb397bf). You should unsubscribe only if you want to cancel the request.

> Because AJAX calls are not streams or events, once they are done they are done... What is the advantage over simple promise, that looks cleaner and
>   destroyed right after execution?

AJAX calls are not just one time event. For example, you can have multiple [progress events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress) with XHR. Promise resolves with only one value, while `HttpClient` can emit multiple HTTP events:

```
export type HttpEvent<T> =
HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpResponse<T>| HttpProgressEvent | HttpUserEvent<T>
```

Comment: I agree that AJAX are more complicated than I stated originally. But 95% of usage is simple - get the data. RxJS states that `unsubscribe` must be called. So I either breach the common usage because I know internals of `HttpClient`, and I can ignore it, or I need to manage the subscription, even though I don't really need to in this particular case.

Comment: @YaroslavVeremenko, Where does RxJs state that you always have to call `unsubscribe`?

Comment: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html
"Represents a disposable resource, such as the execution of an Observable. A Subscription has one important method, unsubscribe, that takes no argument and just disposes the resource held by the subscription."

Comment: @YaroslavVeremenko, it's just an explanation of subscription. It nowhere states that you should always unsubscribe. Also, if observable is hot and shared, you won't be able to dispose resources by unsubscribing

Comment: RxJS itself states that `Subscription` is [disposable resource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispose_pattern). Any disposable resource should be disposed when not used, period. If HttpClient provides the resource that only pretends to be disposable, then something is wrong with the implementation.

Comment: The observable contract guarantees that subscriptions are automatically disposed when the observable errors or completes, thus the explicit unsubscription is unnecessary. Nothing wrong with the implementation and perhaps instead of accusing the developers of not knowing their business you should first study the library before making such statements.

Comment: And FYI, you *can* explicitly unsubscribe if you feel like you have some reason to do so. The subscription will be totally cool with that.

Comment: Thank you @IngoBürk. That was the answer I was looking for. I have seen enough developers not knowing their business to question it. Looking through this [endless text](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) does not help to find the answer Speaking of your comment on the question, no one told me it happens implicitly or who is actually responsible, only that I don't need to call that.

Comment: Just to put it in another way: completion is the producer telling the consumer that it's done, unsubscription is the consumer telling the producer it no longer cares. In either case, the subscription is closed. The important part being that this is a concept of observables themselves and not specific to HttpClient.

Comment: @IngoBürk Thank you again. I have no more questions.

Comment: @IngoBürk, I added the part of releasing the resources when an observable stream completes or errors to my answer. Didn't realize it was unclear. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to unsubscribe on every ajax call. But then you are losing one of the core benefits of Observables - being able to cancel it.

You really need to think about what your code does and what is your standard workflow. What happens if the delete response takes a long time and user clicks it again, or clicks back, or goes to some other page?
Would you like refresh to still happen (since observable will still keep the callback in the memory) or would you rather cancel it?

It's up to you and your application at the end. By using unsubscribe you save yourself from unplanned side effects.

In your case, it's just a refresh so it's not a big deal. Then again, you will keep it in the memory and it might cause some side effects.

Comment: To add on top of that, you can use higher-order Observables to control situation like these in ways Promises can't really replicate. `switchMap` returns an inner Observable but cancels that inner Observable if called again...so using `switchMap` to return the HTTP call Observable means that making another request before the first one completes will cancel the original and only return the latest.

Comment: @joh04667 I am not trying to argue that Observables are bad, but more that Subscription is used for not disposable entity. I talk about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48430082/angular-rxjs-should-i-unsubscribe-on-every-ajax-call/48430834?noredirect=1#comment83853303_48430834)

Comment: @YaroslavVeremenko, observable created by http returns single value, thus works the same way like promise - you call it, once it's done it's gone. You will not get any additional data later. The difference is there is a tiny pause between creation and subscription, in which user can theoretically cancel subscription and bale out before call to backend is made.

With promise there's no way to interrupt the call to backend, other than physically disconnecting the access to backend (as in e.g. disconnecting from the internet).

Hope this clarifies it